# Infinite loop in a custom useFetch hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, render

so I'm not sure, whats exactly causing this or how to fix this properly.

I have a custom useFetch hook to fetching data. The only special thing about it is that you can provide a function to modify the result of the fetch. The useFetch hook was written by some guy I can't reach anymore.

Here's a full, isolated codesandbox example to reproduce this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-lalande-glhg3?file=/src/App.js:192-326

You can see the selected lines (192-326) are commented out. It's a copy of the object above the component.

When commenting in the init-object that is inside the component, the useFetch hook starts infinitely fetching the url.

This will probably have something to do with variables or values changing / rerendering but I don't get it.

Comment: The question is, why set up `init` inside the App function in the first place? Doing it outside works as expected.

Comment: Because in the actual app it's not defined somewhere as a const but is rather called by a function with some params that are coming from a components state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each render creates new object `init` with new reference, but content is the same. Then this effect track this ref AND perform state updates. So then state update leads to re-render, which leads to new init object which trigger effect ...

```
 useEffect(() => {
    setLoading();
    [...successModifiers, (result) => setResource(result)].reduce(
      (previous, current) => previous.then(current).catch(setError),
      fetch(url, init).catch((error) => setError(error))
    );
  }, [url, init, successModifiers]);
//         ^^^^^
```

To solve it you can either persist object ref with `useMemo`:

`const init = useMemo(() => ({ /*...*/ }));`

But this can make usage of `useFetch` a bit clumsy, so alternative is to persist object inside `useFetch` based on deep comparison. Something like this:

```
function useDeepMemo(object) {
  const ref = useRef(object);

  if (!deepEquals(object, ref.current)) {
    ref.current = object;
  }

  return ref.current;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So no matter what happens in the effekt-hook you mentioned, it will loop infinitely as long as the object is defined in the component, right?

Comment: It's right for your case. So you should either create object outside the component or add `useMemo`, if it's not possible.

PS: Technically speaking if effect doesn't trigger re-render (i.e. it's just console.log) it will not create infinite loop.